# Moving my cat to the EU

Tags: netherlands, pets, europe

I was hesitant whether posting this here or in [pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) but I think it fits better here.

I was living in Colombia and moved to the Netherlands, I have made all the required tests to bring my cat with me as stated [here.](http://ec.europa.eu/food/animals/pet-movement/eu-legislation/non-commercial-non-eu_en)

This questions goes specifically to the Rabies antibody test: 
Everywhere I find the same information:

> The test must be carried out on a sample collected by an authorised veterinarian at least 30 days after the date of vaccination and not less than three months before the date of movement

The rabies vaccination was applied in september 2016 and the rabies antibody test was performed in november 2016.

I can't find anywhere when does this test expires! Can I still bring my cat?

Comment: Look at the last note on [this page](https://english.nvwa.nl/topics/travelling-to-the-netherlands-with-your-dog-or-cat/contents/travelling-from-third-countries-to-the-netherlands). The page is a Dutch government, NVWA site.

Comment: @mkennedy please, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it, this is just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Done! I'm glad it was of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow I managed to turn up good information. I found a [Dutch government website](https://english.nvwa.nl/topics/travelling-to-the-netherlands-with-your-dog-or-cat/contents/travelling-from-third-countries-to-the-netherlands) about importing cats or dogs from third countries (not EU) into the Netherlands.

It discusses requirements on whether the animal is coming from a low-risk- or high-risk-for-rabies country.

I will extract just the last few notes from the high-risk section which is what concerned the OP.

- If the result of the test is good, meaning 0,5 IE/ml or higher, the dog or cat can enter the EU after another three (3) months after the blood drawing. This period is for the possible presence of rabies despite the vaccination and positive blood test.

  - This 3-month period shall not apply to the re-entry of an EU pet animal whose passport certifies that the titration was carried out, with a positive result, before the animal left the territory of the EU.
  - The antibody test does not need to be renewed on a pet animal which has been revaccinated against rabies before the validity of the previous vaccination expires.